# SSH permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, permissions, ssh-keys

I have problem logging using ssh to company server.

I have my local ~/.ssh/config;

```
Host target
  HostName xx.yy.zzz.aaa
  User abcd
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentitiesOnly=yes
```

I have other hosts and these works so I don't suppose the mistake here...

On the remote server I added the key to `/home/abcd/.ssh/authorized_keys` via root account and permissions in `~/.ssh/` looks good

```
drwx------ 2 abcd abcd 4096 Jul 31 21:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 abcd abcd 4096 Jul 31 21:07 ..
-rw------- 1 abcd abcd  104 Jul 31 21:14 authorized_keys
```

I also added myself to the `ssh` group and in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I added my username and the ssh group to allowed users/group. Also I've reloaded the sshd `systemctl reload sshd`

```
AllowUsers ab ba abc abcd
AllowGroups admin ssh root
```

The groups shouldn't make so much difference as `AllowUsers` is preferred over it, but it's still there
`ssh-copy-id` won't work as password login is disabled.

But I still get `permission denied (pubkey)` so I must use different temporary accessible account
What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Re-run your SSH command with flags for verbose logging `ssh -vvv <stuff>` and see if there are any hints.

Comment: Suddenly started working, IDK - maybe some SSH cache or sth, sorry for bothering you and thanks for your time :)

Comment: You may answer the question if you've figured it out, or delete it, that way it doesn't hang around unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. All the steps are in the question.

SSH server just needed some time to process the changes.

First the config:

```
HostName 77.111.222.333
User abcd
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
IdentitiesOnly=yes
```

Add your PUBLIC key into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on your server and make sure it's used when connecting into the server

Make sure for the permission are very strict both on server and local

```
drwx------ 2 abcd abcd 4096 Jul 31 21:14 .
-rw------- 1 abcd abcd  104 Jul 31 21:14 authorized_keys
```

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` make sure your username is in the `AllowUsers` list or if not present your group is in `AllowGroups` and verify you're the member of the group running `groups $USER`

If you checked this, try to reload the SSH service by `systemctl reload sshd` and wait until it works.

For hints on what could be wrong use `-vvv` verbose setting of SSH. But it didn't help me much :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).